# PHP 5.3 Tutorial cookies excercise

Tags: php, cookies, php-5.3

Hey guys I'm a beginner in php and I'm learning cookies, Im in an tutorial right now but I'm having issues debugging this exercise which is just suppose to store a name and location cookie.

Heres my php script

```
<?php 

    /**
    * In this example, you create a script that can store the visitor’s first name and location in two browser cookies, 
    * retrieve and display the information from the cookies, and delete the cookies on request.
    **/
    define('URL', 'https://collabbro-bvcxtds.c9.io/app/php-practice/remember-me.php');
    if (isset($_POST['sendInfo'])) {
        storeInfo();
    } elseif (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] == 'forget'){
        forgetInfo();
    } else {
        displayPage();
    }

    function storeInfo() { 
        if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
            setcookie('firstName', $_POST['firstName'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '', '', false, true);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
            setcookie('location', $_POST['location'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '', '', false, true);
        }

        header('Location:' . URL);
    }

    function forgetInfo() {
        setcookie( 'firstName', '', time() - 3600, '', '', false, true);
        setcookie( 'location', '', time() - 3600, '', '', false, true);
        header('Location:' . URL);
    }

    function displayPage() {
        $firstName = (isset($_COOKIE['firstName'])) ? $_COOKIE['firstName'] : '';
        $location = (isset($_COOKIE['location'])) ? $_COOKIE['location'] : '';
    }

?>
```

and heres my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Remeber me user information with cookies</title>
    </head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <!-- nav -->
        <!-- end nav -->
        <h1>Remember User infomration with cookies</h1>

        <?php if ($firstName or $location)  { ?>
        <?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump($firstName); exit(); ?>
        <?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump($location); exit(); ?>


        <p>Hey, <?php echo $firstName ? $firstName : 'visitor' ?> <?php echo $location ? 'in $location' : '' ?>! </p>

        <p>Here's a little nursery rhyme I know:</p>
        <p><em>Hey diddle diddle, <br> 
        The cat played the fiddle <br>
        the cow jumped over the moon <br>
        the little dog laughed to see such sport <br>
        and the dish ran away with the spoon  </em></p>

        <p><a href="<?php URL ?>?action=forget">Forget about me</a></p>
        <?php } else { ?>

        <form action="<?php URL ?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="please enter your first name"/>
            <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Where do you live?"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sendInfo" id="sendInfo"/>
        </form>
        <?php } ?>

        <!-- footer -->
        <!-- end footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Heres what were my debugging steps

First thing I do is vardump() `$firstName` & `$location` inside my condition statement here `<?php if ($firstName or $location)  { ?>`

This gives me nothing so i check my post method to see if its sending back to the page (which it is to my knowledge)

But looking at my code that handles the input everything looks good, dont know whats going on, thanks for the help!

Comment: One possible problem would be that buttons don't always send their value. It's better to check for if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) for saving the cookies.

The next step in debugging would be to set $dummy = true; at the top of your PHP and then if($dummy) { die('It worked');} in your HTML to see if variables from that script are accessible in your HTML template at all.

Comment: @Cuagau i tried testing `$_POST['firstName`] and it works. but still not rendering nothing

Answer (score 0):

I see your code nice. 
Try setting the -3600 in forgetInfo() to -3600*24. The time function is executed in your server, and the cookie is stored in your computer (thus cookie-time is evaluated in your computer). It may be a time difference of many hours.

Comment: but the forgetInfo() function never gets executed yet??? cause nothing is being displayed

Comment: when you inspect the page sourcecode, can you see the line (in your script) *<form action="<?php URL ?>" method="post">* as this (in your browser) *<form action="https://collabbro-bvcxtds.c9.io/app/php-practice/remember-me.php" method="post">* ? [sorry about the ";", I can't delete it, it shouldn't be]

Comment: nice catch, i completely forgot to use the inspect element tool to see what was being rendered. With that being said it was empty until i hardcoded the url, but still nothing :(

Comment: The html code is within the PHP file, isn't it? It must be.

Comment: I'd change "<?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump($firstName); exit(); ?>" to "<?php echo ('<pre>'. var_dump($firstName).'</pre>'); ?> (see the dot instead of ";"). Same following line.

Comment: The $_POST seems to be lost. Instead of post, the request method defaults back to Get. ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]). It seems to be caused only in PHP 5.3 when a warning is issued (see this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5574698/1414176) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93570/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-hello-world).